# Modal Window - Identify the button that calls it via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an Index page that shows a **table** of all the elements of a model called `Machine`.

Each one of the rows has a button that pop-ups a modal window in order to `Edit` the properties of this model.

In the same Index page I have a `Create` button used to add new `Machines`.

Here is the structure:

[image]

The modal window used for both cases (`Create` or `Edit`) is the same.

I need to populate a dropdownlist inside the modal window depending on which button was hitted. If it's a new `Machine`, add a specific value defined on the Javascript, in other case, do nothing.

***The code:***

*The Create button:* It has it's own ID: modalbutton

```
    <div class="btn-group" id="modalbutton">
        <a id = "createEditCustomerModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="CreateEdit" data-target="#modal-action-machine"
           class="btn btn-default">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  Ingresar
        </a>
    </div>
```

*The Javascript:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
            var wasclicked = 1;
        };

        $('#modal-action-machine').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            if (wascliked = 1) {
                var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Modelo --</option>";
                $('#TypeID').html(items);
            }
           var wasclicked = 0;
        });
```

**The problem:**

The idea was to set a variable (`wasclicked`) to 1 when the `Create` button was clicked.

If this was the case, I would populate the property `TypeID` with the value of the `items` variable. **After that**, set the `wasclicked` variable to **zero**.

**Why?** Because, when the `Edit` button was hitted and the modal pop-ed up:

```
$('#modal-action-machine').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
```

Given that `wasclicked` is zero, nothing was supossed to happen.

However, even if I hit `Create` or `Edit`, `wasclicked` is always 1 and I can't differentiate the scenarios like this.

How can I solve this? Why `wasclicked` is always 1? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (insert after doc.ready function):

```
var wasclicked = 0;

document.getElementById("modalbutton").onclick = function () {
  wasclicked = 1;
};

$('#modal-action-machine').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  if (wasclicked === 1) {
    var items = "<option value='0'>-- Seleccione Modelo --</option>";
    $('#TypeID').html(items);
   }
  wasclicked = 0;
});
```

You are using the same variable name (`wasclicked`)in multiple places in your code but given the encapsulation created by your functions, it is actually not the same variable in all places. This code creates a variable outside the scope of your functions and therefore is accessible to both.

You also have a typo in your code:

`if (wascliked = 1)`

It should be `wasclicked`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I'm getting that the `wasclicked` inside the if statement is undefined everytime, altought it's a global variable

Comment: update `var wasclicked` to `var wasclicked = 0` and  `if (wasclicked = 1)` to `if (wasclicked === 1)`